# Google GTM dependencies error

Tags: java, android

i use the GTM and have a question,please help me

app **build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
android {
  compileSdkVersion 25
  buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.york.yorkbbs"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 531
    versionName "5.31"
    multiDexEnabled true
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a"
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
sourceSets {
    main {
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
    }
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = true
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}

lintOptions{
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    abortOnError false
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
}
}

repositories {
   mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'], dir: 'libs')
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
  compile project(':library_googlemap')
  compile project(':library_jcvideoplayer')
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.0'
  compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:10.2.1'
  compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.1'
  apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.1'
  compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:3.1.0'
  compile 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.15.3'//exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
  compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.14.1'
  compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:0.14.1'
  compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
  compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.2.1'
  compile 'com.tencent.mm.opensdk:wechat-sdk-android-with-mta:1.0.2'
  compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
  compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.4.1'
  compile project(':Qupaisdk-release')
  compile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.0'
  compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.6.4'
  compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0.1'
  compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0.1'
  compile 'jp.wasabeef:blurry:2.1.1'
 }
```

project **build.gradle**

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
    classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.3'
    classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.3.1'
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}


allprojects {
   repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0.

thanks~

Comment: There is google-services version difference in your project and other included external library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rectify your `build.gradle`

**No Need**

```
compile project(':library_googlemap') // Remove this line
```

**Finally**

```
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.1'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:10.2.1'
```

Comment: hi library_googlemap is a library, custom the google map action. the library include compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'

Comment: @Len Add `10.2.1` version instead of `old` .Clean-Rebuild and run

Comment: Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0.

Comment: hi Amiya, is that so?

Comment: @Len yes .wait please

Comment: use `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'`

Comment: thanks Amiya, I just  move the apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' to bottom line and is well,